# Loading a CSV file into an HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv, html-table

I want to create a webpage that loads a selected CSV file (from hard drive) and displays its contents using table HTML.

The project incorporates two components and so far, I've been researching the latter; generating a table out of a nested array in javascript.

For some reason, the columns do not appear the way they should.

My code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table id="1"> </table>

<button onclick="createTable()">Create</button>

<script>
function createTable() {
    var array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
 document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ""; //Clear.
 
 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
 document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += "<tr>";
  for (k = 0; k < array[0].length; k++) {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += "<td>" + array[i][k] + "</td>" ;
  }
  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += "</tr>";
   }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A succinct solution based on D3.js: http://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823

Answer (score 6):

Save the table contents to a variable first and set it to the innerHTML afterwards. Everytime you add a `<tr>` (or any not singleton tag for that matter), the browser immediately renders the closing tag.

Try this:

```
function createTable() {
    var array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
    var content = "";
    array.forEach(function(row) {
        content += "<tr>";
        row.forEach(function(cell) {
            content += "<td>" + cell + "</td>" ;
        });
        content += "</tr>";
    });
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = content;
}
```

Because you are planning on using the `FileReader` API, IE9 support is off the table anyways. Updated the above function to use the 'newer' `forEach` array function

---

**ADDENDUM**

To load a file with javascript you have to use the `FileReader` HTML5 API. I can give you some pointers as to how you should go about doing this. This is all ***untested code***, but it gives you a little idea what to do

1.Create a input field

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
```

2.Trigger a response on change of this input

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');
file.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var f = file.files[0];
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var CSVARRAY = parseResult(e.target.result); //this is where the csv array will be
    };
    reader.readAsText(f);
});
```

3.Parse the result to an array by using split/push. This uses `\n` as row delimiter and `,` as cell delimiter.

```
function parseResult(result) {
    var resultArray = [];
    result.split("\n").forEach(function(row) {
        var rowArray = [];
        row.split(",").forEach(function(cell) {
            rowArray.push(cell);
        });
        resultArray.push(rowArray);
    });
    return resultArray;
}
```

(or you can use a third party plugin which will parse the CSV for you: [papa parse](http://papaparse.com/), for instance)

Comment: And in any case, `+=` with `innerHTML` is just really, really poor practice.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm also interested in loading CSV into a nested array like the one above.

Answer (score 3):

After some long searching, [this](https://github.com/MounirMesselmeni/html-fileapi) is probably the most simple and functional script that I could ever come across, also available for free. Although it doesn't deal with the array modification directly, it's easy to edit and elicit your desired results.